# Laravel 7 filter search: Call to a member function where() on string

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, filter

I have a database with these parameters and I'd like to filter search them, it has been working until I added "race" and "dealer experience" and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

dealer_experience is a string, but I don't think that would make a difference ?

Here is my controller code: `  public function index(Request $request){

```
    $title = $request->get('title');

    $type = $request->get('type');

    $category = $request->get('category_id');
    
    $province = $request->get('province');

    $brand= $request->get('brand_id');

    $address = $request->get('address');

    $race = $request->get('race');

    $dealer_experience = $request->get('dealer_experience');

    if($title||$type||$category||$address||$brand||$race||$dealer_experience) {
        $candidates = Profile::query();
        if ($title) {
            $candidates = $candidates->where('title','LIKE','%'.$title.'%');
        }
      
        
        if ($category) {
            $candidates = $candidates->where('category_id',$category);
        }

          
        if ($brand) {
            $candidates = $candidates->where('brand_id',$brand);
        }

        if ($type) {
            $candidates = $candidates->where('type',$type);
            
        }

         
        
        if ($address) {
            $candidates = $candidates->where('address','LIKE','%'.$address.'%');
        }

        if ($race ) {
            $race  = $race ->where('race',$race);
        }

        if ($dealer_experience) {
            $dealer_experience = $dealer_experience->where('dealer_experience',$dealer_experience);
            
        }    
    

        $candidates = $candidates->where('profile_status',1)->paginate(5);
     
        return view('profile.allcandidates',compact('candidates')); 
    }
    else
    {
        $candidates= Profile::latest()->where('profile_status',1)->paginate(2);
     
        return view('profile.allcandidates',compact('candidates'));

    }

}
```

}`

Any and all help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ($race ) {
    $race  = $race ->where('race',$race);
}

if ($dealer_experience) {
    $dealer_experience = $dealer_experience->where('dealer_experience',$dealer_experience);
        
}
```

to

```
if ($race ) {
    $candidates = $candidates ->where('race',$race);
}

if ($dealer_experience) {
   $candidates = $candidates ->where('dealer_experience',$dealer_experience);
        
}
```

Reason, you still want to filter the candidates

Comment: thanks so much ! it is working, however,

race is working, but dealer experience being an integer either 1= yes and 0= none

it only filters if 1 and not if 0, any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not filtering `$candidates`. Also you could do it nicer and more readable by using the `when()` method.

```
$candidates = Profile::where('profile_status',1)
    ->when($request->has('title'), function($query) use ($request){
        $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->title.'%');
    })
    ->when($request->has('type'), function($query) use ($request){
        $query->where('type', $request->type);
    })
    ->when($request->has('category_id'), function($query) use ($request){
        $query->where('category_id', $request-category_id);
    })
    ->when($request->has('brand_id'), function($query) use ($request){
        $query->where('brand_id', $request->brand_id);
    })
    ->when($request->has('address'), function($query) use ($request){
        $query->where('address', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->address.'%');
    })
    ->when($request->has('race'), function($query) use ($request){
        $query->where('race', $request->race);
    })
    ->when($request->has('dealer_experience'), function($query) use ($request){
        $query->where('dealer_experience', $request->dealer_experience);
    });

if ($request->hasAny(['title', 'type', 'category', 'address', 'brand', 'race', 'dealer_experience'])) {
     $candidates = $candidates->paginate(5);
} else {
     $candidates = $candidates->latest()->paginate(2);
}

return view('profile.allcandidates',compact('candidates'));
```

Comment: thank you so much for the suggestion, I tried copying and pasting your code and fixed the typo "->" for category_id, however, I just get a blank screen after doing so. no errors or anything, just a blank white screen under the URL